# React Native Push Notification works on debug but on release - android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-native-push-notification

I see there is an open [issue](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1005) for `react-native-push-notification`. Just wondering if anyone faced this issue.

I have tested my react native app when developing for android 8 and android 9. Push notification does show up in debug on device. But when I build apk from the same code, everything works other than the push notification.

As a note, it is an `expo` application and I use `npx jetify` manually for androidX conversion then `expo publish` and then android release build.

Comment: I am getting same issue. Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered a similar issue and resolved it. there is a PR for this https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/pull/1355

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem by upgrading expo to 37 bare workflow. Since we had a detached expo project from expo 36. The detached version's android application was extended from `ExpoApplication` which does not convert to `ReactAppliaction` when push notification comes in to `react-native-push-notification`.